# shinydashboard sidebar unable to uncollapse multiple tabs

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I have some very simple `shinydashboard` code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id='tab1',
      menuItem('tab 1', tabName='tab1',
        menuSubItem('subtab 1', tabName='tab1subtab1'),
        menuSubItem('subtab 2', tabName='tab1subtab2')
      ),
      menuItem('tab 2', tabName='tab2',
        menuSubItem('subtab 1', tabName='tab2subtab1'),
        menuSubItem('subtab 2', tabName='tab2subtab2')
      )
    ),
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML('$(document).ready(function() {$(".treeview-menu").css("display", "block");})')))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName='tab1subtab1',
        verbatimTextOutput('check11')
      ),
      tabItem(tabName='tab1subtab2',
        verbatimTextOutput('check12')
      ),
      tabItem(tabName='tab2subtab1',
        verbatimTextOutput('check21')
      ),
      tabItem(tabName='tab1subtab1',
        verbatimTextOutput('check22')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe(print(input$tab))

  output$check11 <- renderPrint(input$tab)
  output$check12 <- renderPrint(input$tab)
  output$check21 <- renderPrint(input$tab)
  output$check22 <- renderPrint(input$tab)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the code above, there is some HTML to ensure that the `tab` options are uncollapsed when the app launches. However, if the user collapses one of the tabs, and then uncollapses it, the other tab automatically collapses. This means the sidebar cannot return to its original state of both tabs being uncollapsed. How can this be fixed?

UPDATE: I have modified the code a bit from my original post. This new version has the `observe(print(input$tab))` bit to modify output based on which tab has been selected. The answer provided by GyD below answers my original question, but it doesn't let me keep the `observe(print(input$tab))` functionality that I need.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior was not caused by your js code, it is just how `sidebarMenu` is. If a tab is selected, the other is collapsed automatically.

While I don't know how to set this via js or something, the easiest solution I came up with is to use 2 `sidebarMenu`-s instead of 1.

Again, this might not be what you're looking for, but it should solve the problem of collapsing.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id='tab',
                menuItem('tab 1', tabName='tab1',
                         menuSubItem('subtab 1', tabName='tab1subtab1'),
                         menuSubItem('subtab 2', tabName='tab1subtab2')
                )
    ),
    sidebarMenu(id='tab2',
                menuItem('tab 2', tabName='tab2',
                         menuSubItem('subtab 1', tabName='tab2subtab1'),
                         menuSubItem('subtab 2', tabName='tab2subtab2')
                )
    ),
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML('$(document).ready(function() {$(".treeview-menu").css("display", "block");})')))
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! Easy enough.

Comment: Actually, I have another problem with this. In my original code,  my `server` function I allowed me to have `observe(print(input$tab))`, which I could use to modify actions based on which tab had been selected. It seems like that's not possible now. I could use `observe(print(input$tab1))`, but then that would only allow for the options `tab1subtab1` and `tab1subtab2`, while leaving out `tab2subtab1` and `tab2subtab2`. Is there a way around this? Would a js solution be the only way to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't take into account, that if you have 2 `sidebarMenu`, then you can have 1 item selected each, which is not what you want. So this approach is not the way to go.